# Article type standard conrtroller

Tags: apex, visualforce, knowledge

Why Am i getting "Id value ka090000000QxZw is not valid for the FAQ__kav standard controller" error even when i am passing the correct Id.

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:outputText value="{!FAQ__kav.test__c}"/>
    <apex:outputText value="{!FAQ__kav.id}"/>
    <apex:outputText value="{!FAQ__kav.language}"/>
    <apex:outputText  value="{!FAQ__kav.publishStatus}"/>
    <apex:outputText value="{!FAQ__kav.ArticleNumber }"/>

    <apex:outputText  value="{!FAQ__kav.test__c}"/>
    <apex:outputText  value="{!FAQ__kav.test__c}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You're getting this error on an outputText? Can you post your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `KnowledgeArticleId` instead of `Id` on FAQ__kav.

`select Id, KnowledgeArticleId from FAQ__kav where PublishStatus ='online' and Language = 'en_US'`